# how to delete multiple documents with the rest api?

Tags: api, rest, google-cloud-firestore

The problem is that I have a collection of documents in firestore which I want to delete, but not all of them, only those that have certain fields with a certain value.
The documentation does not say anything about it or is not very clear. I have looked at other questions but cannot understand it.
I have managed to solve it by deleting one document at a time, but there comes a point that I need to delete 100 documents at a time, so I make 100 http request, which I have read is not a good practice.
I delete the documents one by one by calling a function which receives the path of the document to delete and once it receives the response code 200, I delete the next one. But I don't know how to do it if I want to delete many at once. I leave you an example of how I delete one in case someone can help me to delete many.

```
delete_document("mydocpath",http)

func delete_document(path: String, http: HTTPRequest) -> void:
   var url := FIRESTORE_URL + path
   var _error = http.request(url, _get_request_headers(), false, HTTPClient.METHOD_DELETE)
```

Comment: My best bet is that you'd need a batched write for this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/batchWrite Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: Yes, I had seen it, but I don't know how to use it, I mean, I make an http POST request with https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/{database=projects/*/databases/*}/documents:batchWrite, but where I tell it which documents to delete? With a json body? I can't understand the codes in the documentation

Comment: the docs say: batch = db.batch ()
but I don't have any batch method created anywhere, I would have to create it myself, just like I create the delete method, but I don't know what parameters to use or anything like that

Comment: You said you're using the REST API, so you'll have to call the endpoint I linked. If you're using a library, please edit your question to show which library that is (and probably also update the tags to include it).

Comment: I am using the rest api with GODOT, I have to do all methods and all with http request to work. Yes I have to call the endpoint that you linked, but I have to pass some parameters like object (write) , but I want to delete documents not write them, also I don´t know what means object(write), I mean, I think I should pass a string named delete or something like that, my program will no understand Object(write)